# Pen Width font turning to White automatically (Jaspersoft Studio 6.4 Arch Linux Gnome)

Tags: gnome, archlinux, jaspersoft-studio

Im having some glitching issues while using JasperSoft Studio. (using the latest version from the AUR).Im using GNOME.

Steps to reproduce :

Add Text Field. Select it.
Go to Properties -> Borders -> Click on a border on the square.

The Pen Width (1.0 by default) appears for an instant and then "disappears" (Its still there as I can select it but i think the font color becomes white)

This can be temprorarily resolved by going to preferences and toggling the theme from classic -> GTK or vice versa. The resolution exists only for the current report and does not remain for other opened reports. Really annoying bug.

Ive tried Adwaita and GTK other themes etc...but no use. The bug persists.

I have a version 6.1.1 of Jaspersoft Studio on another machine running the latest UBUNTU GNOME and it works near perfectly.I tried running this version of Jasper on arch using various settings but it stops working as soon as I open a JRXML file. Nothing is clickable and I have to kill the process. I am guessing its a GTK issue.

I dont want to go back to using Ubuntu as I love the Arch experience. Can someone help me to run the AUR version of Arch without this glitch.

And if you think 6.1.1 should run fine on Arch...can someone help me overcome the GTK issue (Ive already tried export SWT_GTK3=0; but it doesnt work)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the runjss.sh script (probably in /opt/jaspersoftstudio) and add the line

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Then try running JSS via that script and see if it helps.

I haven't had the same issue as you but I've been having a lot of Gnome-related problems and I'm using the same combination as your - Arch (Manjaro) and Gnome with JasperSoft Studio 6.4.3. Works perfectly since I added that line.

You can also edit the .desktop file to exec runjss instead of the default exec line.